# JSP page to immediately display whenever a new row is added in table?

Tags: ajax

I have oracle dbTable letssay testDbTable having column columnA and columnB.Whenever a new row is added in database table,it should display content of that row on JSP page in following manner.

columnA(value):----- and then columnB(value):........

lestsay after some time a new row is added in testDbTable.
then output should be in two line. Added new row in testDbTable should be aove on previous row that was displayed earlier on JSP page.

columnA(value):----- and then columnB(value):........
columnA(value):----- and then columnB(value):........

But such action should be at same time whenever a new row is added.

The simplest way i could think of that check on database again and again for some predefined lenth of time,but this solution seems to be wasteful and suboptimal to me, so i was wondering is there a better way.

i think there should be  a trigger on table,when a new row is added in db then trigger should be fired and display row content on JSP page. I know "how to create trigger on table" but after that i am blank,how will i display just added row on JSP. After trigger on db table how will i approach? Can Ajax solve my problem like auto refresh or watch on db table or sothing else?
is there anyway i can listen to a trigger on my database from a .jsp script and force my client page to be refreshed ? Can you provide me any example link related to ajax,oracle dbtriggers and JSP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should try [reverse ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Ajax) technology like [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).